# history.push() stopped working after upgrading History to 5.0.0

Tags: reactjs, react-router, history

I have recently upgraded **history** module from `4.10.1` to `5.0.0` and noticed that `history.push()` stopped working. After reverting it back to v4 it starts working.

Using **hash history** with `react-router-redux`

I have already created an issue on their repository but didn't get any response yet. So I thought to try different platform.

May be there's some migration docs that I am missing or its really a bug of History module.

Comment: are you using `hooks` now?

Comment: Not throughout the application but yes on some views.

Comment: try using the `useHistory` hook, which is new in v5

Comment: how does your code look like